# Why not expand the definition of "references" to eliminate the need for "foreign key"?

Tags: sql

Why couldn't the definition of `REFERENCES` be expanded to also support table constraints, and then `FOREIGN KEY` could be eliminated from SQL?

It's clear that the difference between `REFERENCES` and `FOREIGN KEY` is that `REFERENCES` is a column constraint, whereas `FOREIGN KEY` is a table constraint.

For example, `create table T (A int, B int, C int, primary key (A,B), (B,C) references T(A,B) on delete cascade)` is not legal, because you need to have `foreign key` before `(B, C)`, because the constraint refers to multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is verbose and highly explicit. Why? There will be no good answer except for the fact that the [SQL-1992 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) already defined things this way:

```
11.8 <referential constraint definition>

[...]

Format

     <referential constraint definition> ::=
          FOREIGN KEY <left paren> <referencing columns> <right paren>
            <references specification>

     <references specification> ::=
          REFERENCES <referenced table and columns>
            [ MATCH <match type> ]
            [ <referential triggered action> ]
```

`FOREIGN KEY` is just a mandatory keyword in a DDL statement. That's it. One could argue that a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint shouldn't be a higher-class citizen compared to a `UNIQUE` or `CHECK` constraint, hence they all need their appropriate keyword

```
11.6 <table constraint definition>

[...]

    <table constraint> ::=
            <unique constraint definition>
          | <referential constraint definition>
          | <check constraint definition>
```